# Redirect subdomain to an Apache Virtual Host

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, ip, virtualhost, hosts

I have a website "**example.com**" hosted on a provider that allows me to manage my own DNS. I want example.com to point to the provider's IP address but I want "**subdomain.example.com**" to point on my own apache installation on a VPS I have with, of course, a different IP address.

This is what I have done:

> I set the A redirect of example.com to the provider's machine (let's
>   say IP is 1.2.3.4)
>
> I set the A redirect of subdomain.example.com to my own VPS (let's say IP is 5.6.7.8)

Then I connected to my VPS server and changed my apache files like this:

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp\htdocs\mydirectory\mysubdirectory"
    ServerName subdomain.example.com
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\mydirectory\mysubdirectory">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**hosts file**, I add:

```
127.0.0.1       subdomain.example.com
```

However when I ping subdomain.example.com I get an "Unknown host error", nor I can access from my own VPS to the files by browsing that URL.

Am I missing something important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a separate `A` record in your mydomain.com's DNS zone file to point your subdomain to your VPS's IP.

`subdomain       A   5.6.7.8`

If you want, you can add the complete hostname subdomain.domain.com as long as it is followed by a `.` (dot).

`subdomain.domain.com.    A   5.6.7.8`

Comment: Oh.. just the subdomain? I wrote the entire address: subdomain.mydomain.com. I'll try this out and let you know, maybe this is what I was doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: This is almost certainly what is wrong, but it may be worth clarifying your answer to explicitly explain that the record data should only contain `subdomain` and not `subdomain.domain.com` for any future readers

Comment: @wiredmark - you can write the entire address as long as it is followed by a `.` (dot). @BE77Y I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what the final dots I already saw somewhere mean!